# CSS file not found in Spring application

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop a Spring MVC application. The following is my file structure:

```
 -/src
     /main
       /resources
          /css
            main.css
       /webapps
          /screens
             header.jsp
             ....
          /WEB-INF
             web.xml
             ....
```

Here is my `header.jsp` where I want to include the `main.css`.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css"/>">      

<title>Insert title here</title></head>
```

My `dispatcher-servlet.xml` has

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

I am using Spring-security for authentication. Hence in `security-app-context.xml` I have included

```
<intercept-url pattern="/resources/css/main.css" access="permitAll" />
```

When I hit on the url, the css is not loading. I looked at the page-source and the link to the css is the following:

```
http://localhost:8080/BlogWar-1.0-SNAPSHOT/resources/css/main.css
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resources folder should be moved under webapps folder.

```
 -/src
     /main
       /resources
       /webapps
          /resources
             /css
               main.css
          /screens
             header.jsp
             ....
          /WEB-INF
             web.xml

         ....
```

`/src/main/resources` is default maven location where you should place resources that you want to have available from the webapp's classpath

`webapps` on the other hand is the root of the webapp, under which all the static resources (js, css) should be placed